# Monit cannot read content

Tags: url, monit, failed

I've installed the latest version of Monit and created a very basic rule:
alert me when the word "Google" cannot be found on google.com (deface check).

I keep getting following error:
failed to [www.google.com]:443/ type TCP/IP using SSL/TLS protocol HTTP

Should I open some kind of different port if I want to check the content?
Without the content rule it's working just fine.
I already tried opening port 80 and 443.

```
    check host google with address srv1.google.com
  if failed url http://www.google.com
    content == "Google"
    with timeout 20 seconds for 2 cycles then alert
```

Monit is hosted on a Synology NAS.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are trying to access http://www.google.com but it seems google is now only supporting httpS.

Try to change your rule to use HTTPS:

```
if failed url https://www.google.com
```

Syntax is more like (didn't try to validate it so not sure)

```
check host google with address srv1.google.com
  if failed
    port 443
    protocol https
    content = "Google"
       with timeout 20 seconds for 2 cycles then alert
```